# GCC iostream fstream error in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, gcc

I am using Ubuntu 13.10. I am getting some errors for the following code.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    error.set_program_name(argv[0]);    

    if ( argc != 2 )
    {
    //  printf(argv[0] + " usage: fifo_client [string] \n");
    /// cout << argv[0] << " usage: fifo_client [string]" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ofstream out(fifo_file);
    if(out)

        out << argv[1] << endl;

    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

If I run the above program a.c using command

```
gcc a.c -o a

a.c:1:20: fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
 #include <iostream>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
```

I don't know whats the problem.

Comment: rename to `a.cpp`, and use the `g++` command.

Comment: Also the code you show doesn't `#include <iostream`, but the code you compile does. So you're not showing us what you're compiling.

Answer (score 5):

Use g++ instead of gcc. gcc could compile a c++ file if it had the right extension (.cpp for instance) or with the right arguments (`-x c++`) but adding the arguments needed to link with the C++ libraries is far too complex to avoid the simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're mixing C & C++ code and compiling it using GCC.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
```

instead of  `#include <fstream.h>`
anyway your source code is not full to make correct suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code in my compiler and got following error :-

```
test2.c:3:21: fatal error: fstream.h: No such file or directory
 #include <fstream.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
```

so i think your question has typo.

It is because you are mixing c and c++ code, fstream is part of c++. try to run by g++.